# Why does the Messaging Indicator display 3 instances of Inbox?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, email, messaging-menu

A couple of (I believe) interrelated questions regarding the Messaging Indicator:

1. Why does the Ubuntu Messaging Indicator Applet display 3 instances of Inbox ?
2. Why does new email not show up in any of the Inbox references?
3. I would be curious to know why new emails do not light the associated Panel icon.

These is no issue with being able to access and read new mail in Evolution.  Additionally, popups indicate that new mail has arrived.  In and of itself the above noted anomalies are something I can tolerate.  However, this all worked prior to upgrading to 11.04 from 10.10.

Comment: As a note of interest, I do have 3 Pop email accounts I am polling with Evolution.  However, they all three deposit new email in a single Inbox...at leas that is what I believe.

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as I know, each account you set up with Evolution will have its own inbox showing because they do not share the same inbox. I use Evolution with my school email and Gmail addresses, and they have 2 different inboxes in Evolution.
2. I'm not sure myself; I am actually wondering whether this could be filed as a bug report on Launchpad.
3. They do on my system, at least when Evolution is open but its window does not have focus.

Comment: The thing is, each account setup in Evolution deposits email into a single shared Inbox.  What I have seen is that even within the Messaging Indicator only one of the displayed Inboxes ever showed a new mail account prior to me upgrading to 11.04 (I played with Gnome-Shell in Ubuntu 10.10).  Relative to using Mozilla Thunderbird, I am in agreement with point made in bullet item #1 above.